# Serializable Attribute causes API to return null properties with ReadAsAsync

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a need to serialize my `StarShip` objects, so I added the `[Serializable]` attribute. Without this I get an error when trying to serialize it with

```
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(this object obj)
{
    if (obj == null)
        return null;
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

However, when I use

```
HttpResponseMessage.ReadAsAsync<SWAPIResponse<StarShip>>();
```

All the `StarShip` properties are now `null`, where they work fine without `[Serializable]`. Is there a solution to this?

**StarShip**

```
//[Serializable]
public class StarShip : SWAPIEntity
{
    public static string rootUrl { get; } = "starships";

    public string MGLT { get; set; }
    public string Cargo_Capacity { get; set; }
    public string Consumables { get; set; }
    public string Cost_In_Credits { get; set; }
    public string Crew { get; set; }
    public string Edited { get; set; }
    public string Hyperdrive_Rating { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Max_Atmosphering_Speed { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Passengers { get; set; }
    //public Film[] films { get; set; }
    //public Pilot[] pilots { get; set; }
    public string Starship_Class { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

**SWAPIResponse**

```
public class SWAPIResponse<T> where T : SWAPIEntity
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public string next { get; set; }
    public string previous { get; set; }
    public T[] results { get; set; }
}
```

Here is where I actually call `ReadAsAsync`:

```
private static async Task<SWAPIResponse<T>> GetResult<T>(string url) 
    where T : SWAPIEntity
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<SWAPIResponse<T>>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using ReadAsAsync() you have to wait until all the data is received before you can serialize.

Comment: @jdweng I receive all the data, but without [serialize] I can't serialize it into a byte[]. But with [serialize] the data comes through with null properties

Comment: The [serialize] really has nothing to do with the issue.  It just changes the timing a little bit.  Your code is not waiting for the data to get received.due to using Async.  When using Async you must block before doing any processing.

Comment: @jdweng how can it have nothing to do with the issue if it works without [serializable] but doesn't work with it?

Comment: As I said it is just happens to work because the timing is a little slower with without [Serializable] and you receive all the data before bf.Serialize is executed.

Comment: @jdweng I see - I think I understand, but I am `await`ing the `ReadAsAsync` call, so surely it is being blocked before processing? Otherwise how would I set it up to not return all `null`s?

Comment: I don't see the await?  Is an exception causing you to jump over the await?

Comment: @jdweng I added the code to my question, but the answer is no - as I mentioned it works perfectly without `[Serializable]` but with `[Serializable]` all property values are null.. there are no exceptions

Comment: If you are getting an exception then make sure the return object is set to null before calling ReadAsAsync() and then test to make sure the object is not null.

Comment: @jdweng There are no exceptions

Comment: I do no t like the "using" statement.  Often it doesn't report exceptions.  I prefer to replace "using" with "try/catch".  One problem with your code is the "using"  closes the memory stream at the end.  You need to keep the memory stream open so it can be read.   Also make sure you set the position of the memory stream to zero before reading otherwise you don't get any data.

Comment: @jdweng I surrounded the code inside the using with a try/catch and there is no exception. Why would adding `[Serializable]` cause the memory stream to not deliver the data?

Comment: @jdweng I think you have misunderstood the question. I am not calling `bf.Serialize` after calling `ReadAsAsync`. I am ONLY calling `ReadAsAsync`, and it returns null properties when I add the `[Serializable]` attribute.

Comment: @jdweng using does not interfere with raising of exceptions. You are confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked after adding `[JsonObject]` attribute to the `StarShip` class